# 'BCrypt' does not contain a definition for 'Verify'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, bcrypt, password-hash

I am developing an ASP.NET Core MVC web application. For that, I employ Identity UI to handle the user accounts. In identity user instead of the default hashing method (ASP.NET Identity Version 2: PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA1, 128-bit salt, 256-bit subkey, 1000 iterations) I am going to modify it and use a custom hashing algorithm (Bcrypt) as follows:

(I have already installed the NuGet package ***'Portable.BouncyCastle'*** as suggested from the Visual Studio IntelliSense)

**BCryptPasswordHasher.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators;
using System;
using System.Text;

namespace WATERrhythmWeb
{
    public class BCryptPasswordHasher<TUser> : PasswordHasher<TUser> where TUser : class
    {
        readonly BCryptPasswordSettings _settings;
        public BCryptPasswordHasher(BCryptPasswordSettings settings)
        {
            _settings = settings;
        }

        public override PasswordVerificationResult VerifyHashedPassword(TUser user, string hashedPassword, string providedPassword)
        {
            if (hashedPassword == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(hashedPassword)); }
            if (providedPassword == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(providedPassword)); }

            byte[] decodedHashedPassword = Convert.FromBase64String(hashedPassword);

            // read the format marker from the hashed password
            if (decodedHashedPassword.Length == 0)
            {
                return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
            }

            // ASP.NET Core uses 0x00 and 0x01, so we start at the other end
            if (decodedHashedPassword[0] == 0xFF)
            {
                if (VerifyHashedPasswordBcrypt(decodedHashedPassword, providedPassword))
                {
                    // This is an old password hash format - the caller needs to rehash if we're not running in an older compat mode.
                    return _settings.RehashPasswords
                        ? PasswordVerificationResult.SuccessRehashNeeded
                        : PasswordVerificationResult.Success;
                }
                else
                {
                    return PasswordVerificationResult.Failed;
                }
            }

            return base.VerifyHashedPassword(user, hashedPassword, providedPassword);
        }

        private static bool VerifyHashedPasswordBcrypt(byte[] hashedPassword, string password)
        {
            if (hashedPassword.Length < 2)
            {
                return false; // bad size
            }

            //convert back to string for BCrypt, ignoring first byte
            var storedHash = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(hashedPassword, 1, hashedPassword.Length - 1);

            return BCrypt.Verify(password,storedHash);
        }
    }
}
```

In the method `'private static bool VerifyHashedPasswordBcrypt(byte[] hashedPassword, string password)'`, there is a problem in the return statement. the `BCrypt` does not have a definition for `'Verify'`. I searched on the internet trying to find a similar method. but failed to do so.

Following is the error output in error list:

> Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
> Error CS0117  'BCrypt' does not contain a definition for
> 'Verify'  WATERrhythmWeb  D:\Implementations\WebAppAndWebAPI-Recreation\Github014\WATERrhythmWEB-API\WATERrhythmWeb\BCryptPasswordHasher.cs   58  Active

I am grateful if somebody can help me to understand how to rectify the above-mentioned issue, please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Pretty sure that's not the correct package. I think you're after BCrypt.net, found here: https://github.com/BcryptNet/bcrypt.net

Comment: @TiesonT. Initially I also felt it like that. So, now I uninstalled 'BouncyCastle' and installed the 'BCrypt.Net' NuGet package. but, I think it is not compatible with the ASP.NET Core, because, there, I can notice the 'warning' symbol in the package. Still, the problem is not solved. Nevertheless thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: @TiesonT. The error was solved. Not only I should have installed the NuGet package BCrypt.Net but also I modified the return statement like this calling the proper methods: ` return BCrypt.Net.BCrypt.Verify(password, storedHash);`. Then the error was solved.